# Existe algum método nativo do JavaScript que retorne a soma dos elementos de um Array ? Como o array_sum() faz no PHP

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de somar os elementos de um Array. Como o exemplo abaixo:

```js
array_soma = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let resultado = metodo_somador(array_soma);

//Gostaria que nesse console retornasse o valor de 15
console.log(resultado);
```

- Ali no exemplo, o **metodo_somador()** seria um método **nativo** do **JS** (que não consegui encontrar e não sei se existe).
- Porém, **não gostaria de criar uma função, com loops, só para fazer isso**.
- No **PHP** existe o **array_sum()** que é **nativo** e retorna essa soma dos elementos de um Array.

Desde já, agradeço a atenção. 
Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `reduce` e somar o elemento atual à "soma anterior".

```js
array_soma = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let resultado = array_soma.reduce((acumulador, valorAtual) => acumulador + valorAtual, 0);

console.log(resultado);
```

Entretanto, esse método **pode até ser** mais lento que usar um "simples for". [Há esse simples teste de performance para comparar ambos.](https://jsperf.com/reduce-vs-loop/4)

Documentação do reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Esse método não é especificamente para "somar". Talvez até seria mais fácil vc escrever a sua própria soma, caso tenha que ser usada em mais lugares (apesar de ser, realmente, um "simples for"). O método `reduce` existe em várias linguagens e o objetivo dele é, na verdade, "reduzir" um array à um objeto.

Comment: Eu tenho uma humilde opinião de um iniciante. As vezes, acho que o PHP tem uns métodos nativos bem mais específicos para cada caso do que o JS. Talvez essa minha opinião seja por eu ser iniciante e não conhecer ao fundo ambas linguagens.

Comment: Esse método não é especificamente para "somar". Talvez até seria mais fácil vc escrever a sua própria soma, caso tenha que ser usada em mais lugares (apesar de ser, realmente, um "simples for"). O método `reduce` existe em várias linguagens e o objetivo dele é, na verdade, "reduzir" um array à um objeto.

Comment: É, no caso não seria mais ou menos como o array_sum do PHP.

Comment: Você poderia explicar por que o `reduce` é mais lento que o `for`.

Comment: O `reduce` está sendo mais rápido no Chrome.

Comment: Sua resposta, com o uso do reduce, foi a que chegou mais perto da minha necessidade mostrada na pergunta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Quando algo é tão simples assim eu realmente não vejo motivos para existir nativo e provavelmente os desenvolvedores do ECMAScript (vulgo JavaScript) provavelmente "concordam", não que eles não tenham criados funções para coisas triviais em outros casos, mas provavelmente isso depende de fatores impares e decisões que estão fora do nosso entendimento, o pessoal do `https://php.net` é uma comunidade, eles gostam de encher de funções, até para coisas triviais, isso porque é como aquela comunidade pensa (lembrando que nem todos eram bons devs nas primeiras versões do PHP, muita conversa na internet e piadinhas confirmam os problemas).

**Não** existe em JavaScript nada **nativo para contar**, você pode usar `Array.reduce`, mas entender o básico ajuda muito, um simples `for` você atingiria um resultado semelhante e com `for` ainda tem melhor desempenho para executar múltiplas operações, algo como:

```js
var array_soma = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
var resultado = 0;

for (var i = array_soma.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    resultado += array_soma[i];
}

console.log(resultado);
```

**Não precisa** esperar existir uma função para cada coisa trivial que necessitar, se é simples então use o simples, se vai mesmo usar essa função em uma série de lugares diferentes e quer facilitar, então faça algo como:

```
function array_sum(arr) {
    let resultado = 0;

    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        resultado += arr[i];
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

No uso ficaria:

```js
var array_soma = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
var resultado = array_sum(array_soma);

console.log(resultado);


function array_sum(arr) {
    let resultado = 0;

    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        resultado += arr[i];
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

---

### Benchmark (teste de performance)

Efetuei um teste de performance local, via Nodejs, que este não tem tanta interferência de outros processos, veja o resultado:

> Array.reduce x 135,434,338 ops/sec ±0.37% (94 runs sampled)
>
> Simple for x 146,437,628 ops/sec ±0.60% (94 runs sampled)
>
> For into function x 145,747,268 ops/sec ±0.34% (93 runs sampled)
>
> Fastest is Simple for

Mesmo o for dentro de uma função conseguiu 10.000.000 operações **por segundo** a mais que o `Array.reduce`.

O teste "online" não é tão confiável, mas de qualquer forma você pode experimentar e ver a diferença em https://jsbench.me/8rk60td9hs/ (teste online), resultado no Chrome:

> [image: benchmark no navegador]

Comment: Obrigado, Guilherme Nascimento. Mas a questão do For eu entendo. É até bem simples de fazer. Eu só gostaria de saber se existe algo semelhante ao array_sum() do PHP. Se fosse pra fazer com for, certamente já teria feito aqui. A questão é que eu gostaria de fazer com coisas nativas. Ultimamente estou tentando utilizar mais as coisas nativas das linguagens para conseguir aprender mais.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. eu entendi perfeitamente a sua pergunta, e o intuito da resposta é justamente esse, pra que uma função nativa para algo tão trivial? Se é tão simples faça na mão, já resolve e se você for usar muitas vezes a tal função então escreva você mesmo a sua função, como eu mostrei na resposta. PS: se existisse nativo ou se um dia existir eu editarei a resposta e adicionarei isto.

Comment: Percebi que no JS não existem tantos métodos nativos quanto o PHP. Mas é só minha opinião de iniciante.

Comment: Mas, Guilherme, qual o problema de utilizar funções nativas ? Acredito que exija bem menos linhas de código e seja algo que foi criado especificamente para aquilo. Pra que criar algo que já exista outra coisa que já faça aquilo ?

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. justamente porque não precisamos de tantos métodos nativos, o PHP só faz por conveniência ou porque alguém da comunidade de mantenedores achou legal, mas na pratica tem muita coisa que é trivial, por falar nisso tem algumas funções em PHP que não são tão boas quanto aparentam e volta e meia temos que escrever algo na mão.

Comment: Entendo, Guilherme. Agradeço a ideia.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. eu não falei que tem problema usar o nativo, eu não disse isso em momento algum, eu estou falando que é algo trivial para ser adicionado ao motor javascript de um navegador, é tão simples que os desenvolvedores também devem concordar, não tem pq fazer uma função para cada coisas simploria, é chover no molhado. O php só faz isso pq é uma comunidade cheio de gente que fica querendo facilitar o que não é dificil e complicar o que era fácil... sim a comunidade de DEVs do PHP não é boa.

Comment: Eu achei a questão do array_sum no PHP uma coisa formidável e super útil a para sua finalidade. Assim como outras funções nativas que facilitam muito.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. mas é trivial, pq o que busca é resolver algo que já é simples, eu acho um monte de coisas formidáveis, em PHP e fora dele, assim como eu acho um monte de coisas horriveis em PHP e fora dele, uma coisa é vc gostar, outra coisa é ser tão simples que nem precisa existir nativo, quando começar a se apaixonar por programar  de verdade (compreender algoritimos complexos e gostar disso), vc vai usar o nativo quando existir sempre que possivel e usar algo que escreve na mão com seu conhecimento e vc vai achar essa combinação formidável também.

Comment: Eu concordo, Guilherme. Nesse meu caso é realmente uma coisa simples. A minha dúvida é somente se existe ou não. Eu gostaria de saber se existe algo específico para isso. Mas se não tiver, fazer com um For não seria problema.

Comment: É porque como iniciante, eu gosto de aprender a grande maioria das sintaxes possíveis da linguagem. Mas o seu modo de pensar não está errado. Esse meu caso seria muito simples resolver, e não seria necessário fazer algo específico para ele. Mas já que existe em PHP, achei que talvez existisse em JS.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. eu entendo que você é iniciante e por isso a minha resposta é otima para este caso, porque ela explica coisas boas para iniciantes e para quem quer evoluir.

Answer (score 3):

Mais uma versão para o Guilherme colocar nos benchmarks :D

```
  var i = arr.length;  // use let se o ambiente for moderno
  var sum = 0;        
  while (i--) sum += arr[i];
```

Segue demonstração:

```js
var array_soma = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
var resultado = array_sum(array_soma);

console.log(resultado);


function array_sum(arr) {
  var i = arr.length;  // use let se o ambiente for moderno
  var sum = 0;        
  while (i--) sum += arr[i];
  return sum;
}
```